# Python basic class understanding

Tags: python, class, oop

So I'm trying to understand the basics of Classes and objects. I have small example that I'm trying to figure out but I am not fully understanding it. Here is the example:

You need to create a simple class such that a call to the `meow()` function of the class `Cat`(as in the example below):

```
kitty = Cat(3)  
kitty.meow()
```

prints "I have 3 lives" to standard output.

This is what I have so far.

```
class Cat(?):
    def __init__(self, kitty):
    self.kitty = kitty
    def meow(self):
        ??
kitty = Cat(3) kitty.meow()
```

Comment: I don't recommend starting here! If you don't know how to print output to the console, you're probably not ready to learn how to write classes. This is a simple snippet but there's a lot going on here, and it's probably too soon. Your indentation and basic syntax aren't right either....do you know how indentation works in python? Did you mean to put the last two statements on one line, too? Why are you assigning `self.kitty = kitty`? This question really needs clarification, *at best*. And cats have 9 lives, not 3...

Comment: Also, I know you're new to StackOverflow, so don't feel bad....I got a ton of downvotes in my early days here....I still do sometime. But get in the habit of googling "python classes tutorial" and "how do classes work in python" etc before coming to SO and saying "WHAT IS GOING ON what is class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, lives):
        self.lives = lives
    def meow(self):
        print "I have " + str(self.lives) + " lives"

kitty = Cat(3)
kitty.meow()
```